Kid has a special power of electricity received from alien when he was born
I'm trying to find the name of a movie that was probably made between 1980 and 1998.
It's about a kid who has a special power that he received from aliens when he was born - it allows him to control electricity. At one point he used/triggered his power with his finger while on a merry go round. After several years, the aliens come back to get him, but he decides to stay. So then the aliens take his power and go back to their planet.
What is the name of the movie?

Although there is no alien in this movie but the story seems to be similar to the one you have asked


A young bald albino boy with unique powers shakes up the rural community he lives in and has incredible intellect and is able to sense the thoughts of the people around him. Jeremy's brain possesses a powerful electromagnetic charge, which causes electrical objects to function abnormally when he is around them, as well as when he becomes emotional. The electrical charge also prevents hair from growing on his body. Jeremy's mother was struck by lightning while pregnant with him; she died shortly after the strike, but Jeremy survived. His father disowned him shortly after his premature birth, and he was raised by his grandparents. Jeremy lived in the basement and worked on their farm, never leaving their property and learning everything he knew from books. He is taken from his home when his grandfather is found dead of natural causes. Jessie Caldwell (Mary Steenburgen), a child services psychologist, takes him to a boys' home because he is now effectively a ward of the state.Jessie enrolls him in high school, where Jeremy meets physics teacher Donald Ripley. Donald finds out that Jeremy has supernatural powers as well as the highest IQ in the history of mankind. While his abilities mark him as special, they also make him an outcast. On a hunting trip with his schoolmates, Jeremy is threatened with a gun by John Box (Bradford Tatum), an aggressive student who views him as a freak. Before John can fire, a gun goes off in the distance, and everyone rushes to see that Harley Duncan, a Sheriff's deputy, has shot a doe. Anguished by the animal's death, Jeremy touches the deer and Harley, inducing in Harley what the students assume is a seizure. However, Harley admits that Jeremy had actually caused him to feel the pain and fear of the dying deer. Because of the experience, Harley removes all of his guns from his house, although Sheriff Doug Barnum allows him to remain as a sheriff's deputy without a sidearm.

More...

No my dear that is not the movie. I watched it 15 or 18 years ago. There was an alien. alien group they came and they went.  But thanks for your reply.

The movie is titled BEIBEI THE LIGHTENING.  The boy actually decided to give up the powers so he could lead a normal life. He had to have an earth wire dangling to the ground, otherwise anyone he touched received an electric shock. The more he exercised the stronger his electrical power got. In a school football game his power increased so much that opposing team players got shocks and we're thus not able to foul him and he scored the winning goal.
I watched this when I was a kid. Can't find the movie on the Internet though.
If you find it anywhere let me know pls.

Probably wrong name

Can you refer to film link from Wikipedia, IMDb etc. Can't able to track which film you are talking about
